# What is the faster way to execute the query rather than Replace () in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

I am trying to replace few strings in a column and add them into a new column. However, the query processing time is so slow and I also feel the 'like' is making it more slow. is there any other alternative method to reduce the time for processing? This is my current code:

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    *,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE
        (REPLACE(_NAME,'Test.S103.S103.SVs.Nozzle1.si_InTemp1','Temp1'),
    'Test.S103.S103.SVs.Nozzle1.si_InTemp2','Temp2'),
    'Test.S103.S103.SVs.Nozzle1.si_InTemp3','Temp3'),
    'Test.S103.S103.SVs.Nozzle1.si_InTemp4','Temp4'),
    'Test.S103.S103.SVs.Nozzle1.si_InTemp5','Temp5') As 'temperature_test'
FROM 
    [MGBAIS].[dbo].[Temperature]
WHERE  
    _NAME LIKE '%Test%'
ORDER BY 
    _TIMESTAMP DESC
```

Comment: Why not just replace 'Test.S103.S103.SVs.Nozzle1.si_In' with blank?

Comment: what do you mean with blank? I need to replace it with a specific value like 'test1' because the original column contains a long string

Comment: In your example you are replacing *Temp1 with Temp1, *Temp2 with Temp2 and so on. Is that not your actual requirement?

Comment: yes thats the actual requirement

Comment: But then right, The original value contains S103.S103....Temp1 which i am trying to shorten to Temp1

Comment: What Shree.Pat18 is trying to show you is that every case you showed us is replacing "Test.S103.S103.SVs.Nozzle1.si_In" followed by something else with just whatever the something else is.  You could considerably simplify this example by replacing all those Replace functions with ONE that says Replace(_Name,'Test.S103.S103.SVs.Nozzle1.si_In','')

Comment: this Replace(_Name,'Test.S103.S103.SVs.Nozzle1.si_In','') will only replace once right?

Comment: the problem right now is, all those values are in same column.. so if i simplify it to a common one, i cant really differentiate it

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be very helpful.  Does the name need to be replaced more than once in the string?  Is there a blahblahblahInTemp6?

Comment: It seems everyone is focused on the REPLACE - and you have some good advice there.  As for performance you are looking for any strings that have 'test' in them - but you are only replacing where the string begins with test.  So - change to this: LIKE 'Test.%' - and if you have an index on that column it should perform much better.

Answer (score 1):

Just an option ... you can use `STUFF()`

**Example**

```
 Declare @S varchar(max) = 'Test.S103.S103.SVs.Nozzle1.si_InTemp1'
 Select stuff(@S,1,charindex('Temp',@S)-1,'')
```

Results

```
Temp1
```

If single digit Tests, you can also use `right()`

```
 Declare @S varchar(max) = 'Test.S103.S103.SVs.Nozzle1.si_InTemp1'
 Select right(@S,5)
```